# Function Default Given as Vector

Tags: r, function

In the help file for some functions, the defaults are sometimes given as vectors. An example is:

`?base::rank`

This opens a help file in which the usage is shown.

Usage:

```
 rank(x, na.last = TRUE,
      ties.method = c("average", "first", "last", "random", "max", "min"))
```

In this example the default for `na.last` is `TRUE`. But, the default for `ties.method` is given as a vector. What exactly does this mean in terms of which is chosen by default? And, more importantly, why is it written this way in the first place?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default is the first value. It is written that way so that you can see at a glance all of the possible options.

Internally, the function will use `match.arg` to evaluate user input and match it to the vector used. This matching is done using `pmatch` (p for *partial* matching), so that the argument can be abbreviated. For example, `rank(x, "first")` can be abbreviated to `rank(x, "f")`. See `?match.arg` for more details. Quoting the `?match.arg` Description:

> `match.arg` matches `arg` against a table of candidate values as specified by `choices`, where `NULL` means to take the first one.

`match.arg` is commonly used when there are a small to medium number of possible options for an argument.

Comment: Interesting. That explains why things like "pairwise" work in cor(). Thanks!